# Python string substitution showing 0.000 in print statement for floating point #

Tags: python

I have this simple python code,

```
import time
t1 = time.time()
total = sum([x for x in range(1000) if x%3 is 0 or x%5 is 0])
t2 =time.time()

print "Ans is: %d, Time is %f" %(total,(t2-t1)*1000.0)
```

I get this as my output

```
Ans is: 233168, Time is 0.000000
```

How come I can't see the result of my number? I've googled other examples of substituting a number in a string and they do exactly what i'm doing, any help?

I've also tried using %0.3f and %d as well....hmm... Thanks in advance for the help

EDIT

When I try this code:

```
import time
t1 = time.time()
total = sum([x for x in range(1000) if x%3 is 0 or x%5 is 0])
t2 =time.time()
print t2
print "Ans is: %d, Time is %f" %(total,(t2-t1)*1000.0)
```

I get this answer,

```
1344350841.39
Ans is: 233168, Time is 15.000105
```

Comment: Odd, I get `Ans is: 233168, Time is 250.000000` as output (v 2.7.2 under XP SP2 in IPython, and about half the time under the regular Python shell) -- are you like on a *super-fast* machine?? What if you change range to a much much larger value?

Comment: Can't reproduce, I get `Ans is: 233168, Time is 0.349045` (Python 2.7.3, Mac OS X)

Comment: It's likely that on your operating system, the clock's resolution is too low for there to be a difference between the two time points. Try `print t1 == t2` and see if it's `True`. (What is your OS?)

Comment: For timing an operation, you should use the timeit module.

Comment: Also: change `x%3 is 0` to `x%3 == 0` (and for 5).  `is` tests identity, not equality.  It only works accidentally due to how integer objects are preconstructed.

Comment: print t1==t2 does return True; I'm on a Win XP, i5 M 540 @ 2.53 GHz cpu, pc.... I'm going to check out the timeit module...this is weird

Comment: cant reproduce this, works fine for me: `Ans is: 233168, Time is 0.999928`

Comment: it seems that when I print t2, i get an answer for (t2-t1)*1000.. strange, i feel like its a number type problem.

Comment: *Very* strange, especially given that you said `t1 == t2` is `True`. Please try printing both times `print t1; print t2`, and then see a) if they're identical and b) if the `(t2 - t1) * 1000` works afterwards.

Comment: Also, have you tried `import timeit; timeit.timeit("sum([x for x in range(1000) if x%3 is 0 or x%5 is 0])", number=1)`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct answer to your question, but in case you use Windows I'd rather recommend to use clock(). According to the doc it behaves differently on UNIX/MacOS.

```
from time import clock
clock()
total = sum([x for x in range(1000) if x%3 == 0 or x%5 == 0])
print "Ans is: %d, Time is %f" %(total,clock())
```

Comment: using clock()*1000 gives me,
Ans is: 233168, Time is 0.319035, all these variations in results are strange, now i don't know what to trust for timing...

Comment: I dont know why you multiply with 1000 but the result is correct. The operation is fast and you can trust it. It of course varies a little depending on other tasks you are running at the same time.